# Using an image map in Dreamweaver CS5 with a Jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, image, dictionary, undefined-reference

I'm currently trying to use an image map on a webpage I am building. When I draw the maps and add links, the page takes me to an an error for an "undefined" web address. I have multiple hotspots in one image, and I believe something with the jQuery is messing me up. Below is my jQuery code. I'm fairly new to web design and any help would be appreciated.

```
}).click (function () {
    window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: are you sure that is your complete code? Missing jQuery selector preceding `click`. You should see an immediate error thrown in console

Answer (score 0):

If you can't step through the code, debug it like this:

```
}).click (function () {
    alert( $(this).find('a').attr('href')) ;
});
```